# How to avoid loading data repetitively in python class

Tags: python

I invoke a python class in my python file. The python class I invoked will load big data from disk.

```
# invoke python class
import mypythonclass
def method():
  for i in range(100):
    mypythonclass.dosomething(params)

# code in mypythonclass
def dosomething(params):
  # load data here
  # do something
```

My question is how can I avoid load data repetitively in `mypythonclass`, thanks.

Comment: Maybe initialize data in `__init__` and then use `self.data`? Or use a global variable?

Comment: Hi  Carcigenicate, the params have nothing to do with the data should loaded from disks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data you are loading will be used by the class instance, you may initialize the data when instantiating the class.
For example:

```
class MyPythonClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def dosomething(self, params):
        # use self.data
```

If possible you should move the class instantiation out of the for loop, so the data is loaded only once. But the example you provided, doesn't have sufficient details, so it is know exactly what you want.

If the data does not change across different instances of the class, you can use class attributes and make `dosomething` a class method.

```
class MyPythonClass(object):
    data = some_data
    
    @classmethod
    def dosomething(cls, params):
        # use cls.data
```

In this case, the data will be available by all the instances of the class.